# Using aliases in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by, alias

The following code is working fine:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(U.username, U.users_id) AS users_name,
    CONVERT(varchar(20), H.date_time, 103) AS date_time,
    SUM(sale_val) AS sales_val
FROM
    res R
        INNER JOIN invoice_hdr H ON H.guid = R.guid
        INNER JOIN users U ON U.user_no = H.user_no
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(U.username, U.users_id),
    CONVERT(varchar(20), H.date_time, 103)
```

But I find the GROUP BY clause redundant, and tried GROUPing BY aliases:

```
GROUP BY
    users_name,
    date_time
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid column name 'users_name'

Same for `date_time`. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: I think you can do `group by 1,2` which are the column numbers in your query.

Comment: Tried and got the following: "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wrapping it in a subquery and performing aggregation on the outer level:

```
select sq.users_name, sq.date_time, sum(sq.sale_var)
from (
SELECT
    ISNULL(U.username, U.users_id) AS users_name,
    CONVERT(varchar(20), H.date_time, 103) AS date_time,
    sale_val
FROM
    res R
        INNER JOIN invoice_hdr H ON H.guid = R.guid
        INNER JOIN users U ON U.user_no = H.user_no
) sq
GROUP BY sq.users_name, sq.date_time;
```

`ORDER BY` is the only place where you can reference an alias **on the same level with its definition**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RR.users_name,RR.date_time,SUM(RR.sale_val) Sale FROM 
(
SELECT
    ISNULL(U.username, U.users_id) AS users_name,
    CONVERT(varchar(20), H.date_time, 103) AS date_time,
    sale_val 
FROM
    res R
        INNER JOIN invoice_hdr H ON H.guid = R.guid
        INNER JOIN users U ON U.user_no = H.user_no

        ) RR
GROUP BY
    RR.users_name,
    CONVERT(varchar(20), RR.date_time, 103)
```